# Ordered list changes to unordered list in rDiscount with Octopress

Tags: jekyll, octopress, rdiscount

I had been struggling to *understand* why rDiscount would render my markdown as such .. my original intention was to render the following:

1. list one ordered
2. list two ordered
3. list three ordered

   - unordered sub-first list
   - unordered sub-second list
4. list four ordered

But somehow, I am unable to obtain the same with `rDiscount` using Jekyll as site generator and `octopress` as a blogging framework. The exact problem is after having that `*` which starts an entire sub-unordered list, it still continues to be in unordered format even if `4` was specified precisely.

The `docs` says if I continue to write `1,2,3` and in middle of any, if I chose to `*` in-between, it would render as sub-order (unordered) but the use case of the same hasn't been obtained. How should i approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried indenting the unordered list using tabs? In Markdown this separates the list into a main list and a sub-list.

Comment: Yes, i have tried indentaion as well with same results being obtained.